# gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input

Tags: git, gpg, gpg-agent

I am trying to run the command:

```
 git secret reveal
```

But I am getting error: `gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input`

I have followed: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent

GPG works fine e.g. when commiting, etc.

Comment: SSH keys have nothing to do with GnuPG in this instance (reganding the text you're linking to).

Comment: You seem to be using [git-secret](http://git-secret.io/). On `git secret reveal`, it will use GnuPG to decrypt the files that are added to the git repository in encrypted form. To do that, it needs to ask you the passphrase of your GnuPG private key - and for that, it needs a terminal device, so that it can do the asking securely, making the input invisible. So the context is important: **exactly how** are you trying to run that command? Locally? Over a SSH connection? As a non-interactive remote command, e.g. `ssh somehost git secret reveal`?